# Parse JSON with PHP: Syntax complication

Tags: php, json, parsing

I'm getting the following errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: value in C:\fileSystemLocation/phpFile.php on line 43
Notice: Undefined index: value in C:\fileSystemLocation/phpFile.php on line 44
```

when I'm trying to parse the following json data:

```
"data":[
"phone":[
    {"value":"",
    "primary":true
    }],
"email":[
    {"value":"",
    "primary":true
    }]
]
```

With the following statements

```
$response = json_decode($json_response, 1);

// Gets the count of records returned from the api. Used in the for loop to go through response 1 array element at a time. 
$count = Count($response['data']);

//create array of the json data we want to export to csv
for ($x=0; $x<$count; $x++)
{
    $jsonDataInArray[] = array
    (
         "phone" => $response['data'][$x]['phone']['value'],
         "email" => $response['data'][$x]['email']['value'],
    )
}
```

What is wrong with the syntax of the above 2 statements? I'm wondering if there is any error with my syntax above specifically with `"phone" => $response['data'][$x]['phone']['value'],
                            "email" => $response['data'][$x]['email']['value'],`

Comment: One suggestion: build a PHP object matching what you expect to get, then use `json_encode` & output the results so you can see what the string should look like.

Comment: use `json_decode()`. what you are doing is wrong.

Comment: `['data'][$x]` does not exist in your JSON?

Comment: `"phone" => ['data']['phone']['value'],
"email" => ['data']['email']['value'],` remove `[$x]`. it not exist anywhere.

Comment: I didn't include all of the code. More is included now

Comment: @pHorseSpec please mark and up-vote the answer for others help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your JSON data is missing `{}` (malformed) and, also, you're using a `phone` key (alphabetical) on a numerical key array (`[]`). To use alphabetical keys you have to have a dictionary (`{}`, key-value arrays). Looks like your JSON should be like this:

```
{
    "data" :
    [
        {
            "phone" :
            {
                "value" : "",
                "primary" : true
            },

            "email" :
            {
                "value" : "",
                "primary" : true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Also remember that the function to count items in an array is `count()`, not `Count()` (capitalization matters).

I would do this then:

```
$jsonDataInArray = array();
$response        = json_decode( $json_response, TRUE );
$data            = $response['data'];
$count           = count( $data );

foreach ( $data AS $index => $object )
{
    $values = array(
                "phone" => $data[$index]['phone']['value'],
                "email" => $data[$index]['email']['value']
    );
    array_push( $jsonDataInArray, $values );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the syntax that worked for me:

```
"phone" => $response['data'][$x]['phone'][0]['value'],
"email" => $response['data'][$x]['email'][0]['value']
```

The ending objects in the json data looked like (WARNING: not the whole string of json data, just the end):

```
"phone":[{"value":"","primary":true}],"email":[{"value":"","primary":true}]
```

and since there are arrays, I have to include the `[0]`

The following code:

```
"phone" => $response['data'][$x]['phone']['value'],
"email" => $response['data'][$x]['email']['value']
```

Would work with these ending json data objects (WARNING: not the whole string of json data, just the end):

```
"phone":{"value":"","primary":true},"email":{"value":"","primary":true}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax inside your loop is wrong. Change:

```
"email" => $response['data'][$x]['email']['value'],
```

To:

```
    $email = $response['data'][$x]['email']['value'];
```

Comment: I've included more code to show that this is occurring within an array. Sorry for the confusion, but this isn't the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to finish your question, before asking for an answer.

Comment: Well, I thought the original code would have sufficed for answering my question, I was wrong, and included more code. That's what edits are for! ;)

Comment: @pHorseSpec Your only question is "What is wrong with the syntax of the above 2 statements?" to which you are getting valid answers.  Perhaps the issue is that you cannot structure/explain your question well.  People are trying to help you..

Comment: I included more info in the question. Let me know if I should include more. My apologies for sounding rude.